# Does LaTeX support the sarcmark?

Tags: symbols, punctuation

Does LaTeX have an escape sequence for the open source [sarcmark](http://opensarcasm.org/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\textexclamdown` is an inverted exclamation point:

[image: example]

(found via [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html))

Answer (score 10):

Writing `` !` `` (exclamation point followed by a backtick) is very easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Example: !`
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know the backtick had that effect.

Comment: I'm stumped; I've got no idea what's happening. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Hendrik: It's treated by TeX as a ligature. LaTeX defines `\textexclamdown` as alias (in OT1) in ot1enc.def: `\DeclareTextCommand{\textexclamdown}{OT1}{!'}`.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand: It's not TeX but depends on the font.

Comment: of course it depends on the font!  the glyph has to be there, after all.  but latex will support \textexclamdown for any font it directly supports (e.g., t1-encoded ones, in which the glyph exists.